# Pencil and Paper Package on Overleaf

Tags: packages

I wanted to use the [Pencil and Paper Package](http://www.qdds.org/index46f5.html?id=129) on Overleaf but cannot get it to work. The answer commands seem to work fine but there is an issue with `\question{\bf ...}` commands or more precisely with `\bf` as the output returns

```
Class scrreprt Error: undefined old font command `\bf'.

See the scrreprt class documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10 ...studentische Wohngemeinschaft bezeichnen?}
```

wheras line 10 looks like this:

```
\question{\bf W�rden Sie die Personen bzw. Personengruppe, die zurzeit in Ihrem Haushalt wohnt, als studentische Wohngemeinschaft bezeichnen?}
```

and the whole file is an example from the package and looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{paperandpencil}

\begin{document}

\question{\bf W�rden Sie die Personen bzw. Personengruppe, die zurzeit in Ihrem Haushalt wohnt, als studentische Wohngemeinschaft bezeichnen?}

\begin{linkanswers}
\framedlink{Ja}{{\em Bitte weiter mit} {\bf\em Frage $32$}} // Line 13
\nolink{\pbox{Nein}}[0.25cm]
\nolink{\pbox{Wei\ss{} nicht}}
\end{linkanswers}

\line

\question{\bf Ist Ihr Haushalt mit den folgenden Dingen ausgestattet?} // Line 20

\begin{compactitem}[-]
\item Farbfernsehger�t

\begin{linkanswers}
\linkwithquestion{\df{Ja}}{Haben Sie das derzeit benutzte Ger�t in den letzten 12 Monaten gekauft?}{\pbox{Ja}\quad\pbox{Nein}}
\nolink{\pbox{Nein}}
\end{linkanswers}

\item Videorecorder
\begin{linkanswers}
\linkwithquestion{\df{Ja}}{Haben Sie das derzeit benutzte Ger�t in den letzten 12 Monaten gekauft?}{\pbox{Ja}\quad\pbox{Nein}}
\nolink{\pbox{Nein}}
\end{linkanswers}

\end{compactitem}

\end{document}
```

The same error occurs as well for line 13 and 20. The only files I have in my project are the `main.tex` and the `paperandpencil.sty`. Normally Overleaf works fine with external packages but this one seems to have issues.

**Update:** Using not Overleaf but Sublime also returns the same error and it's the same when using `\bfseries` or `\textbf{}` instead and not using `\bf` at all, just `\question{...}`

Comment: Well, KOMA classes warn you about the outdated `\bf` command. Use `\bfseries` or `\textbf{Ist Ihr Haushalt...}` instead. The encodings seems to be wrong as well

Comment: although the documentation has a 2009 date, it is likely to be older than that.  the package (or at least the documentation) wasn't created by overleaf; they just seem to have picked it up from somewhere else.  it's not on ctan.

Comment: I tried using Sublime and not Overleaf and still get the same error. Also changing it to `\bfseries` or `\textbf` results in the same error as well.

Comment: I've obtained the `paperandpencil.sty` file from the given link and the error is already in there: It uses `\bf` and even `\bf{...}` :-(

Comment: The error is not connected to `Overleaf` at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `paperandpencil.sty` file uses the deprecated `\bf` command on two (actually three occasions)

Short after the start of the file it redefines `\thechapter`

```
\renewcommand*\thechapter{\bf{\arabic{chapter}.}}
```

and later on in a `\newcommand` usage:

```
\newcommand{\categories}[2]{{\bf #1}&& {\bf #2}\\[0.2cm]}
```

So correcting the errors in the OP will still not be sufficient since the real error is inside `paperandpencil.sty`.

Applying `\renewcommand` for both macros with `\textbf` or `\bfseries` replacing `\bf` after the package has been loaded will silence `KOMA`'s warning.

Other possibility: Use `enabledeprecatedfontcommands` as option to `scrreprt` (not recommended, since not really official, as far as I know)

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{paperandpencil}

\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}.}}

\renewcommand{\categories}[2]{{\bfseries #1}&& {\bfseries #2}\\[0.2cm]}


\begin{document}

\question{\textbf{Würden Sie die Personen bzw. Personengruppe, die zurzeit in Ihrem Haushalt wohnt, als studentische Wohngemeinschaft bezeichnen?}}

\begin{linkanswers}
\framedlink{Ja}{{\em Bitte weiter mit} {\textbf{\emph{Frage $32$}}}}
\nolink{\pbox{Nein}}[0.25cm]
\nolink{\pbox{Wei\ss{} nicht}}
\end{linkanswers}

\line

\question{\bfseries Ist Ihr Haushalt mit den folgenden Dingen ausgestattet?}

\begin{compactitem}[-]
\item Farbfernsehgerät

\begin{linkanswers}
\linkwithquestion{\df{Ja}}{Haben Sie das derzeit benutzte Gerät in den letzten 12 Monaten gekauft?}{\pbox{Ja}\quad\pbox{Nein}}
\nolink{\pbox{Nein}}
\end{linkanswers}

\item Videorecorder
\begin{linkanswers}
\linkwithquestion{\df{Ja}}{Haben Sie das derzeit benutzte Gerät in den letzten 12 Monaten gekauft?}{\pbox{Ja}\quad\pbox{Nein}}
\nolink{\pbox{Nein}}
\end{linkanswers}

\end{compactitem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note** I also switched to `utf8` encoding.

Comment: I don't recommend this package at all

Comment: Thank you, this is also basically what I did after your first comment. Opened up the package and changed the internal bf command to textbf. What other package would you recommend for creating surveys?

Comment: @Someguy: Usually, one should not change the package code itself. Either patch or redefine the macros, but there might be statements in the package code that are effective, that can be changed not without editing the code itself. Here, it was possible with `\renewcommand`, but there might be other issues in the package which are not obvious on first glance but might occur on special occasions when being used